# Observe a Process of Unknown PID (no UI)

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos-carbon

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172032/detecting-whether-a-process-starts-and-finishes-with-notifications-in-cocoa) question, but even when is close to what I need, is useless

Basically, I have an app that needs to do something when another process (of known name) is launched and/or terminated, but i don't have the PID, so i can't set a kqueue to look for it.

I could do a while for "ps aux | grep processtolook | grep -v grep" command, but that's my last resort.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you know the name of the process/program of which you want the pid?

Comment: have a look at my answer if it helps you.

Comment: Generic process or an Application? If an app, see NSRunningApplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this answer: [Determine Process Info Programmatically in Darwin/OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220323/determine-process-info-programmatically-in-darwin-osx).  The libproc.h header file has `proc_listpids` which will get you all the pids.  You can then get the pid information in a loop and using `proc_pidinfo` and check the name.  Looking at the top source as suggested there might also be worthwhile.  (The current verson is here http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-67/.)

Unfortunately, this is an undocumented interface and subject to change at any time.  Also, it isn't the quickest thing, since you have to loop over all the processes in the system.  In general, this isn't a great way to do this.

A better way might be to write a new processtolook that simply invoked the old one which you can move or rename.  It could then notify you of the process start and stop.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: +1 for last paragraph. That's the real solution: replacing the program to be watched with a wrapper that notifies your program.

Comment: No, is not a posibility since is a System invoked process (is invoked by OSX when a keystroke is met) and I shouldn't mess with User's systems configurations right? Anyway, I choose your answer because is what I was doing without NSTask :)

Answer (score 1):

If the target process/program name which you want the PID is "processtolook" then you can use `pidof` command to get the PID of that running program.

`pidof processtolook`

have a look at the `pidof` manual. This is a part of `sysvinit-tools` package.

**EDIT1:** 
Have a look at this code i found: http://programming-in-linux.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-process-id-by-name-in-c.html

This might help you get you the outline.

Comment: Is the same as using "ps aux | grep processtolook | grep -v grep" conceptually, and i need to know of it during runtime, so it would be a while of "pidof processtolook" which is what i want to avoid. Besides, is not part of Mac OSX

Comment: Have a look at the EDIT1, i have provided a link i found.

Answer (score 0):

On BSD you can use kvm_openfiles and kvm_getprocs to implement what you want. I don't know if it's available on OSX. If you have a pgrep program, look how it's implemented (src/bin/pkill.c).